# Android. onPostExecute with several try-catch blocks

Tags: java, android, try-catch

First of all, I have almost no experience in Java. I'm using `AsyncTask` to get some data from my server and in the `onPostExecute` method I need to use several try-catch blocks to manage the received data. If one of them fails (catch is executed) the app should stop execution and show a dialog. But when any catch block is executed, the following try-catch blocks are executed, and that's what I want to avoid. I can't use `return` because `onPostExecute` returns void.

So, what is the best way to manage this situation to achieve what I need?

Comment: after any exception is caught by catch block, code execution is stopped right away, you can use finally instead to show your dialog or you could use methods to check where exceptions can occur. To be more clear post your code where you are facing problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a Method returns Void, you can use "return;" to exit the method.

So in the Catch block, Show the Dialogand Exit with return;

Elsewhere you can catch different exceptions in one try block.

Comment: I didn't know I can use just `return;`. Thanks.